# How can I update my entries with pdo::FETCH_CLASS and query it into my database?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Iam trying to update my form fields with a simple update statement. However when I execute the statement it wont update.

Iam using PDO::FECTH_CLASS to store my values into my object, and thats how I check if the id is equal to the id I want to update.

This is my code:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
try{

  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $paragraph = $_POST['paragraph'];
  $company = $_POST['companyName'];

  $q = 'UPDATE `testimonials` SET paragraph`= :paragraph,
                                  `name`= :name,
                                  `company`=:company,
                                  `dateAdded`= NOW()
                                   WHERE `id` =:id';

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($q);

  $stmt->execute(array( ':id' => $testimonials->getId(), ':paragraph' => $paragraph, ':name' => $firstname, ':company' => $company));


}catch( PDOException $Exception ) {
   throw new MyDatabaseException( $Exception->getMessage( ) ,  (int)$Exception->getCode( ) );
}


}
?>

<section>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <label for=""></label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $testimonials->getName();?>">
    <input type="text" name="companyName" value="<?php echo $testimonials->getCompany(); ?>">
    <textarea name="paragraph"><?php echo $testimonials->getParagraph(); ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: What error are you getting (if any)? Have you done a `var_dump($testimonials->getId());` to verify that it is returning what it is supposed to?

Comment: I do not get any errors, And when I var_dump retrives the id(3)

Comment: Please include the exact contents of the var_dump. Nothing in your code seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I get:
string(1) "3"

Comment: Does it work if you hard code the ID to a value of 3 (not '3')?

Comment: Are you missing an open ` in `paragraph\``

Comment: If I hard code the id  then it still wont update.

Comment: @NigelRen bet that's it but I would have expected an error to be thrown. Amazing how you can look at something over and over again and miss silly simple stuff like that.

Comment: @NigelRen That was the problem ! You guys are awesome! Thank you so much.